# The name 'context' does not exist in the current context

Tags: telerik, blazor, blazor-client-side

Here's My code:

```html
<TelerikGrid Data="@forecasts"
                 Sortable="true"
                 FilterMode="GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
                 Resizable="true">
        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Title="Date">
                <template>
                    @{
                        var forecast = context as WeatherForecast;

                    }
                </template>
            </GridColumn>
        </GridColumns>
    </TelerikGrid>
```

What am I doing wrong[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those rare times when case matters in an HTML tag. Instead of:

```
<template>
    @{
        var forecast = context as WeatherForecast;
    }
</template>
```

You need:

```
<Template>
    @{
        var forecast = context as WeatherForecast;
    }
</Template>
```